# C, segmentation fault, either by printf or string declarations

Tags: c

I have "included" anything I could find, I have tried every which way to declare strings, to dereference a string, to print a string and I'm STILL getting a segmentation fault. I'm using ubuntu, and I am getting a segmentation fault, and I don't know why. I have been reading every version of errors from string declarations, from printf etc, and I have found nothing that works.

It won't even printf("test");

Ideas?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("test");
    char *string = "hey dude what's up";
    printf("test");
    char **strings;
    char *tempString;
    printf("test");

}
```

Comment: Can't reproduce here. Could you give us the output from GDB and/or valgrind?

Comment: It should at least the first printf if you changed it to `printf("test\n");` Do you recognouze the diff?

Comment: If you haven't already, try using a debugger to pinpoint the problem. Sounds like you have a system issue rather than an issue with your code so it will be difficult for anyone else to find it for you.

Comment: @giorgi The missing `return 0;` is not the answer.

Comment: @giorgi Undefined for anyone reading the program's exit code. But not for the statements.

Comment: @giorgi `return 0;` is assumed in C99.

Comment: how are you compiling it?

Comment: yeah the missing return 0 is because this is only the head of a larger file. I can't even get the printf("test"); to work so I came here. I'm using ubuntu command line with gcc to compile. I'll look into valgrind.

Comment: as @ott wrote, you must use `printf("test\n");` with the `newline` to flush the buffer, otherwise you will not reliably see how far the program got before it failed.

Comment: we really appreciate it when posted code that has a run time problem cleanly compiles.   The posted code causes the compiler to raise several warnings. 1) unused var string, 2) unused parameter argc 3) unused parameter argv 4) unused variable strings 5) unused variable tempString

Answer (score 0):

in the posted code, after correcting all the compiler warnings, the following is left.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>


int main( void)
{
    printf("test");
    printf("test");
    printf("test");
    return(0);
}
```

Which does NOT seg fault;

Remembering that stdout is buffered by the OS, nothing will print until the program exits or the buffer (which is very large) overflows.

However, to make each 'test' string print immediately, either

```
1) follow each printf() with fflush(stdout)
or
2) modify 'test' to 'test\n'
or
3) follow each printf() with an input statement, like fgets or getchar or ...
```

given the original code:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("test");
    char *string = "hey dude what's up";
    printf("test");
    char **strings;
    char *tempString;
    printf("test");

}
```

any effort to modify a literal, like using strtok() will result in a seg fault event because the literals are in readonly memory

To make the code more robust, the char pointers 'strings' and 'tempString' should be initialized to NULL.

It is bad programming practice to name variables with only a trailing char difference 'string' and 'strings' as such practice can and will be a maintenance nightmare.

I would also suggest not naming variables the same as the header files being used ('string' and 'strings' and 'string.h') Note: there is also a 'strings.h' header file

BTW: the original code compiles with warnings, links with no warnings, and runs with no seg fault event.

or course, there is no output to the terminal until the program exits, again, due to the buffering of stdout.

I'm running ubuntu linux 14.04

Comment: what the above means is the problem in the code that is causing the seg fault event is not in the posted code